# task id as thread name in thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I need to create a thread from the thread pool and need to pass a *task id* - a unique id that kept in my `Runnable` object - as the thread name.

I looked in to the `ThreadFactory` interface, but in that I couldn't pass any additional parameter as thread name to the thread created. Also, I looked at the `DefaultThreadFactory` class. It uses an `AtomicInteger` to set the thread name.

Can I pass an arbitrary string to the factory and have it use that string as the name of the thread created?

Comment: The created `Threads` are not for tasks themselves; they're for the workers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the name of the thread executing your task as:

```
class YourTask implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
    Thread.currentThread().setName(getTaskId());
    //.. rest of the code for the task
  }
}
```

This is probably what you want anyway. A thread that is created by the thread pool might be used for executing many different tasks - so giving the thread a name which is dependent on the task that it will eventually run is not possible.

Comment: Yes, and it's not possible not because of developers laziness, but because it's a bad idea. Let me rephrase that: **BAD IDEA**.

Answer (score 0):

I think manually setting the taskId on each thread scheduled on thread pool is not the most elegant way to do it. 
You can implement ThreadFactory interface like this -

```
public class NamedThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory{
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        if (r instanceof NamedRunnable) {
            NamedRunnable namedRunnable = (NamedRunnable)r;
            t.setName(namedRunnable.getTaskName());
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

And your NamedRunnable will be like this -

```
public interface NamedRunnable extends Runnable{
    String getTaskName();
}
```